# How can there be two identical vanity plates in the same driveway?

Tags: united-states, vehicle-registration

I drive past a house each day on my commute.  There are two cars parked in the drive, and each appears to have the exact same vanity plate (from the same state).  It's a six-letter word, such as COWBOY.  As far as I know, each license plate in a given state should be absolutely unique, so how can this be?  And since the vehicles are parked in plain view, wouldn't any law enforcement officer driving by be likely to see them and investigate?

The only possible explanation I can come up with is that since license plates in this state can have 7 characters, perhaps one plate is in the system as _COWBOY and the other as COWBOY_.  But they look identical.  Could an extra space before or after a word in a vanity plate be used to make 2 unique plates out of the same single word?

Comment: Are they indeed state-issued license plates mounted in the required location? Some states don't require front license plates, in which case you may be able to put whatever you want there.

Comment: Yes, state-issued, and both were seen on the rear of the vehicles.

Comment: Well, O and 0 look pretty similar…

Comment: They do, but i made up that word to protect the innocent...  The plate in question does not include the letter O.  It does include I, but the font in use on plates makes the letter I easily differentiated from L and 1.

Comment: which state are the plates in? In Germany, there are [special Interchangeable license plates](https://www.tuningblog.eu/en/kategorien/tuev-gesetze-verbote/wechselkennzeichen-454311/)

Comment: I believe my state, Vermont, allows the same character strings to appear on different kinds of plates. So there could be a COWBOY pleasure car plate, a COWBOY truck plate, and a COWBOY municipal plate.

Comment: Good point, but these are both plain old cars!

Comment: Are they the same plate design / background?

Comment: @JonCuster yes, same plate design/background!

Comment: Are both of the vehicles routinely in use? If a car is just parked in your driveway long-term, it could have an older issue of the same plate, or a spare.

Comment: If there are no pictures, it didn't happen. More seriously, a picture might help discern what is going on. There may be details not mentioned in the question that matter.

Comment: Please specify the state.  It's possible that your state's license plate laws only apply when the vehicle is on public roads.  So maybe the vehicles don't run, or they're not driven off the property; or if they are, maybe the owners affix the vehicles' proper plates when they do so.

Comment: It could be that they were issued as front and rear plates for the same vehicle (if your state does that), and that the owners for some reason put the front plate on the rear of another vehicle.  Again, whether or not that's legal could depend on the laws of the specific state, and on the circumstances.  Does your state do registration stickers on license plates?  If so, are they present and current on both vehicles?

Answer (score 2):

Made up words (but close enuff), but I know a person who has "HISPEED and "HI SPEED" on two of his cars in Virginia. Same plate design.

Details matter.

And H1SPEED and HISPEED are also 2 different combinations.

From the Virginia DMV, all it says is that the characters must be "unique". The style of plate does not enter into it.

"Personalized character combinations for license plates registered to a vehicle must be unique."

dmv.virginia.gov/vehicles/license-plates/personalized-policy

Comment: Can you provide a legal citation beyond just your anecdote? Right now, this seems more like a comment.

Comment: From the Virginia DMV: "Personalized character combinations for license plates registered to a vehicle must be unique. " https://www.dmv.virginia.gov/vehicles/license-plates/personalized-policy

Comment: I would recommend including that with relevant citations in the answer.

Comment: In the OP's answer, you could also have something like COW_BOY and C0W_B0Y and it would be valid (The second plate tag uses Zeroes and not Capital Letter "O".